# Does elevation not work within Android Home Screen Widgets?

Tags: android, android-widget

Tried all sorts of different ways to do this but not matter what view I apply an elevation to (such as android:elevation="10dp") it does not render correctly on a Home Screen Widget.

Is this a known limitation, that home screen widgets do not support elevation. I am running this on an Android L device so its should not be a compatibility issue.

If this is impossible I figure I could use 9-patch or layer-list drawable to achieve a similar but not as good effect.

Comment: Haven't heard of a limitation, but if you could post a sample xml for a widget that has the issue, maybe we can discuss further. What widgets for  example? Elevation seems to be working for CardView in my case.

Comment: Sorry there is some confusion. I am talking about an Android widget that lives on your home screen, not a Widget such as (View, ListView, CardView etc)

Comment: No worries; I updated the question to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've played with all widgets I have on my phone (both with Nova Launcher and Nexus 5 stock launcher, which is Google) and none of them have this feature, even Google apps (excluding Google Now!).

I've added `app:elevation="10dp"` on my widget and I think that it is not possible to have this feature on **Widget** directly, without playing with code and fantasy.

If you really want a widget that include elevation design, just "copy" the style of Google Now widget.

[image]

I suppose that they have a transparent layout (the black parts on image) wich contains another layout (grey) *with elevation* and grid filled with **CardView** *with elevation too*.

Let me know if you want an example code.